# How to give jupyter cell standard input in python?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a program on a jupyter notebook that accepts user input, and I cannot figure out how to get it to read standard input. For example, if I run the code with shift-enter:

```
a = input()
print(a)
```

the cell indicates it is running, but does not accept input from me. How do I get it to accept input?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: On chrome with jupyter notebook version 4.0.6 this works fine.

Comment: I am using Chrome. What happens for you when you hit shift-enter?

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley a small input box appears under the current cell. I can there enter my input.

Comment: Ok, I restarted my computer, and everything worked fine. I have no clue what happened the first time....

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the `raw_input()` (for Python 2) or `input()` (for Python 3) methods.

Example code:

```
a = raw_input()
print(a)
```

Example notebook:

[image]

Comment: They are already doing that, so what was the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same problem, using the input in jupyternotebook, it blocks the execution and it does not work until restarting the program, so I added a print () after each input and my program is working.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you hit Shift-Enter a second time without completing the first input with Enter, so the kernel was always waiting until the first command completed, before executing it again. If you use in the menu

"Kernel", 
"Interrupt",

all active commands are stopped (including the second execution of the box) and the problem should be solved without restarting the computer (or the browser / the kernel).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right, you ony have to restart the kernel (over the Run button)

Comment: So every time they want to take user input they have to restart the kernel? That doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 2):

Update, it works as `input()`
I noticed this thread is old, but still shows up in search results. So, here is the right way. You can use `input()` in the ipynb notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
print(input('Write anything:'))
```

Answer (score -1):

use raw_input instead of input if you are using python 2 version. if u still getting same problem then,

click on kernel then "restart and run all" 
and try to run the code again. 
this will fix it.