# Inputs within loop in jupyter lab cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm running a jupyter lab notebook
I have a list of names and I want to be able to input some information for relationships between each item in the list.

My thought would normally be to iterate through a for loop but I don't think in jupyter it is possible to loop through inputs.

```
names = ['alex','tom','james']
relationships = []
for i in names:
    for j in names:
        if j==i:
            continue
        skip = False
        for r in relationships:
            if r[0] == {i,j}:
                skip = True
                break
        if skip == True:
            # print(f'skipping {i,j}')
            continue
        strength = input(f'what is the relationship between {i} and {j}?')
        relationships.append(({i,j},strength))

print(relationships)
```

This works if i run it in terminal but not in jupyter lab, what might work?

Comment: I ran your code in jupyter and got in the end [({'alex', 'tom'}, 'good'), ({'alex', 'james'}, 'bad'), ({'james', 'tom'}, 'nice')]. Is this not what you are expecting? Maybe post how your cells look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further simplify your code using `itertools.permutations()`.

Example:

```py
import itertools

names = ['alex','tom','james']

unique = set()
permutations = set(itertools.permutations(names, 2))

for pair in permutations:
    if pair not in unique and pair[::-1] not in unique:
        unique.add(pair)

relationships = []

for pair in unique:
    strength = input(f'what is the relationship between {pair[0]} and {pair[1]}?')
    relationships.append((pair,strength))

print(relationships)
```

Console Output:

```
what is the relationship between alex and james?12
what is the relationship between alex and tom?5
what is the relationship between james and tom?6
[(('alex', 'james'), '12'), (('alex', 'tom'), '5'), (('james', 'tom'), '6')]
```

---

However, even your code seems to be working fine in jupyter notebook:

[image]

You can maybe try restarting the python kernel i.e. in the menu go to Kernal -> Restart and Run all.

---

Related question:

[How to give jupyter cell standard input in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968112/how-to-give-jupyter-cell-standard-input-in-python)