# Why can't I use input() in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, jupyter-notebook

When I try to use the `input()` function in Jupyter Notebook, it looks like the notebook becomes unresponsive.

For example when I try this code:

```
print('Enter your name:')
x = input()
print('Hello, ' + x)
```

a box shows up asking for the input, and when I type something in and run it, nothing happens. The asterisk symbol appears in parenthesis at the beginning of the line as if the notebook is busy, and it just stays like that. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me. What about IPython, does it work for you there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give jupyter cell standard input in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968112/how-to-give-jupyter-cell-standard-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the kernel. You will find the Kernel option on the toolbar. After this choose the Restart and clear output. It worked on my notebook.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue, solution for this is to press `CTRL` + `Enter` instead of `Enter` or `Shift` + `Enter` after giving input.

Answer (score 0):

You can click to stop the kernel and then run it again:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine for me. But can try it the other way like this:

```
x=input('Enter your Name: ')
print('Hello, ' + x)
```