# how to get ln[]: in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

[here how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRDw.jpg)

I am new to the notebook and my code doesn't output. It just pretends all the code like as text.  I suspect it is because I am not creating appropriate cell. every example on the internet has ln function near the cell and I just don't have that. how do I solve my problem? thx.

Comment: What you want? You should learn from this https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-with-jupyter-notebooks/creating-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: You've got an `input()` call there. Have you provided any input yet?

Comment: it doesn't prompt for input at all. when I run it, it does nothing.

Comment: my question is why I see [*] instead of ln[*] ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968112/how-to-give-jupyter-cell-standard-input-in-python) might be related/helpful.

When you load the notebook, what do you see?

Comment: Using jupyterlab is fine. The asterisk `[*]` indicates that the cell is running and waiting for you to press enter in the textbox area below the cell (as previously mentioned). The lack of asterisk as in `[ ]` indicates that the call has not be run. The presence of a number e.g. `[1]` means that the cell finished running. Your cell started running but cannot finish because it is waiting for input (this is entering a value in textbox). If you do not see the textbox you might be using an outdated jupyterlab version; it cannot be said from the screenshot because it is showing too little.

Comment: What do you mean by `ln[]`? I have never seen that

Answer (score 0):

To run the code in the cell press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> or go to the top menu **Cell > Run Cell**.

Answer (score 0):

[*] means the code in the cell is running and as you had asked for input from the user, the cell is waiting for receiving the input from the user. It will keep on showing the [*] until you provide input and press the entre button. After pressing the entre button, the input will be stored in the name variable. And finally, that input will be printed as `Hello NAME!`. After the code runs successfully, the [*] will be changed to [1].
In your case, the cell is waiting to receive the input from the user. So, as soon as you provide the input, the cell will be executed successfully.