# Input function is not working as expected in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

This simple one line code is running for more than 1 minute and showing this error.

I have installed jupyter notebook in VS code and using miniconda instead of anaconda...I couldn't get the issue.

[image: Picture:]

### **The 2 line code is:**

```
my_number = int(input("enter a number: "))

print(my_number)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10048/2282921608.py in <module>
----> 1 my_number = int(input("enter a number: "))
      2 print(my_number)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: What did you type in the input?

Comment: Your program is acting as if you've sent an empty string as input. I don't know how that particular environment works, but I'm guessing that it's waiting for you to type some input and hit enter in the terminal, but it's timing out after a minute and sending the blank string, thus throwing that error. Again this is just a shot in the dark. I don't know if any console input is even accepted in this case.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968112/how-to-give-jupyter-cell-standard-input-in-python

Comment: Try restarting your Jupyter kernel

Answer (score 0):

Please input an integer in the input box, instead of a float or empty.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]